# Substitute function back into solution

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I have a expression

```
G[x] := (1-x^2)(1+A*x)(1-a*x)
```

where $(a,A) \in \mathbb{R} $.
Now this heavily simplifies some other expression. But these expression are no longer in terms of $G[x]$ and I want them to be.
Essentially I was hoping I can just run the following code

```
ClearAll[G]      
   expre = ( (1 + a^2 A^2 x^2 y^2))/(A^2 (x - y)^2 (1-x^2)(1+A*x)(1-a*x)) /.(1-x^2)(1+A*x)(1-a*x) -> G[x];
expre
```

And get the result

```
( (1 + a^2 A^2 x^2 y^2))/(A^2 (x - y)^2 G[x])
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use simplify with side relation instead of `/.`

```
expr1 = ((1 + a^2 A^2 x^2 y^2))/(A^2 (x - y)^2 (1 - x^2) (1 + Ax) (1 - ax))
expr2 = (1 - x^2) (1 + Ax) (1 - ax)
Simplify[expr1, {expr2 == G[x]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Are you sure `ax` is not meant to be `a*x`? Same for `Ax`?

Comment: Yes thank you, exactly what I needed.
Yes I did mean `a*x` and `A*x`. I will edit it for future readers.